# ASP.NET MVC 5 Bundler considered import statements?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, webpack

I have the question referring to the bundler in ASP.Net MVC 5.

As I know you can use the bundler for bundling and minification. Currently I work on a vue-tempate and I have a lot of import statetments at the beginning like:

```
import Vue form "vue";
```

So my question is does the bundler resolve this import statement in the finale output file? So that I dont have to include

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

I haven't found a clear answer on Google.

Currently I use webpack to achieve this, but I was wondering if this is really necessary.

Please note this has nothing to do which approach is better I just want to know if the standard bundler is able to do the same.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Turn on bundling and see what the output contains.

Comment: @freedomn-m in my test it dont do it out of the box. But I thought maybe you have to configure somehting else to achive this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mix MVC and framework JS is ever hard to know on what you include between server side and client side.

If you are using `App_Start/BundleConfig`, you can create a virtual path to reference in _Layout the framework once as this example :

```
        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/vue").Include(
            "~/Scripts/lib/vue/vue.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/lib/vue/vue-resource.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/lib/vue/vue-router.js",
            "~/Scripts/lib/vue/vue-mask.js",
            "~/Scripts/lib/vue/v-calendar.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/lib/vue/vue-config.js"
            ));
```

You can import your `Vue` each time it is necessary, and webpack would be produce the same bundle as your example shown.

If the issue is only `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>` in each template view, then you can add this on _Layout and using `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js`

Comment: thx for the anwser. So I guess the bundler is not able to resolve the import statements, so this is the best solution.

Comment: No, the MVC bundler produce only virtual path to minified files.